# Terminal CMD + SHIFT + Left/Right Brace No Longer Works

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

I'm using Terminal and don't know if this has been an issue after upgrading to Mountain Lion, or whether I made a configuration change that had a side effect that I didn't realize. When I use the CMD + SHIFT + ] or CMD + SHIFT + [ keys, the mac beeps at me instead of switching the tab I'm using in Terminal.

Is there a way to remap this sequence? Where would I look?

Note, I can use CMD + SHIFT + ] / [ to shift tabs in Safari and Chrome, so this only happens in Terminal. (I also noticed that CMD + 1, shifts desktops instead of shifting to a particular tab; I'm okay with that not operating as I would expect since I don't use that shortcut).

Note, I have switched my CMD & ALT keys on my keyboard, but if I use a keyboard without these switched, I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Disregard the first part. [ Is the shift of { so we were saying the same thing different ways. I'm leaving this here though regarding disabling the Mission Control shortcuts.

The sequence to cycle forward through tabs is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>, despite what the Window menu says. (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> switches between windows. Very odd.) And <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> cycles backward.

[image: Terminal's Window menu with incorrect keyboard shortcuts displaying for cycling tabs]

(You should also be able to reclaim <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. to switch windows in Terminal, which is what the Window menu says those shortcuts do, by going to System Preferences > Keyboard and disabling the keyboard shortcuts that use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ a number under Mission Control. I haven't tested this though.)

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard Preference Pane]

Comment: Ok, This indicates the issue. I'm using MacOS in Swedish. It's making an assumption that I'm using a Swedish-keyboard and the mappings are CMD + Ä and CMD + Ö. I'm using an English keyboard. Is there a way to change the shortcuts for the select next and previous tab.

Comment: System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts tab, click on Application Shortcuts on the left, then under the right window click the + button. Choose Terminal from the Application drop-down menu (hint: you have to go to the bottom of the menu and select Other, go into the Utilities folder, and select it there), for Menu Title enter `Select Next Tab`, click in the Keyboard Shortcut field and press the keyboard combination you want. Repeat these steps, except the second time enter `Select Previous Tab`.